# Moving two specific files into its parent folder within multiple directories with unique names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, applescript

I need to move two specific files, we'll call them fileA.txt and fileB.sh into its parent folder.

One of these files is generic but the other file is specific to its parent folder and can't be copied to all folders.

The folder hierarchy goes like:[Folder Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ovc.jpg)

The parent folder is unique and has to stay the same. There are over 2000 folders total located in subfolders of 200-300 parent folders containing the child folders

What I have so far that in BASH thats not working is:

```
find -maxdepth 4 -type f -name ‘*.bb’ ‘*.txt’; mv ../.
```

I am VERY new to scripting and I know this is a very simple task. I apologize for the terrible drawing but I've hit my head against the wall for too long.

Answer (score 3):

To move any file named `fileA.txt` or `fileB.txt` to its immediate parent directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 4 -type f -name 'file[AB].txt' -execdir mv {} ../ \;
```

Or, to move any file named `fileA.txt` or `fileB.bb` to its immediate parent directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 4 -type f \( -name 'fileA.txt' -o -name 'fileB.bb' \) -execdir mv {} ../ \;
```

#### How it works

- `.` tells `find` to start with the current directory.  (You can replace this with any directory that you like.
- `-maxdepth 4` tells `find` not to descend more than four levels deep into the directory structure.
- `-type f`  tells `find` to look only for regular files.
- `-name 'file[AB].txt'` tells `find` to look only for files that match the glob `file[AB].txt`.

  Alternatively, to match either `fileA.txt` or `fileB.bb`, we use two `-name` tests combined with a logical-or (`-o`) and grouped together with parens:

  ```
  \( -name 'fileA.txt' -o -name 'fileB.bb' \)
  ```
- `-execdir mv {} ../ \;` tells `find` to chdir to the file's directory and run the shell command `mv {} ../` where `find` will replace `{}` with the file's actual name.  The expression `../` is Unix-speak for parent directory.  The trailing `\;` merely marks for `find` the end of the shell command

Comment: What an incredibly well explained answer! I figured out an alternative workaround that doesn't work as broadly but I am going to set up a few test folders and try this again so I can learn from it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, if I wanted to remove the child folder after removing the files from it, would I just add a ; -rm at the end or would that remove the new parent directory?

Comment: @J.Mike  While written thanks is nice and likely appreciated by the answerer, an excellent way to demonstrate gratitude for a person's help is to select their answer as the accepted one (if, of course, you feel it deserves this).  Here's a useful guide on [what do to when someone answers your question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).